# How to convert remove trailing slash of URL rewrite rule from IIS web.config to ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an IIS server rewrite rule I want to convert to the `IApplicationBuilder` and `RewriteOptions` in ASP.NET Core. My `web.config` for the remove trailing slash rule is [fairly common](https://www.rewriteguide.com/iis-add-remove-trailing-slash/) and looks like this:

```xml
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

How do I, if possible, convert this to C# and ASP.NET Core? My `Startup.cs` file could look like this as starting point:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions());
}
```

I tried searching for this, but couldn't find any results.